# Determine textfield from toolbar IOS

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I am trying to set up undo and redo for each textfield and unsure how to figure out how to determine which text field is the first responder.

Is there an argument I can pass into the methods called by the buttons from the toolbar, or do I need to do some fancy footwork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea:

If the `viewController` becomes delegate of each `textField`, then the `viewController` will get notified as each `textField`'s value changes, or becomes first responder.

To adopt the delegation, you will do:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end

@implementation
- (void)someMethod{
    // for a series of textfields
    myTextfield1.delegate = self;
    myTextfield1.delegate = self;
   // or you hook the delegate in IB
}

// then you get notified
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // textField here that gets passed in as an argument is the first responder
    // if you have, let's say tag number for each
    NSInteger activeTextFieldTag = textField.tag;
}
@end
```

Here is the reference to [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Comment: This is a good answer. We use a similar technique quite a bit.  In addition to unique tags on text fields, we add a private `UITextField` property to the view controller in question to track the current-editing text field (with the property being assigned in -textFieldDidBeginEditing:).

Comment: I did not go as far as tagging the text fields, but this worked perfectly. I just grabbed the current text fields undo manager into a ivar, and when done editing set the ivar to nil.